# Microsoft.Bot.Connector.BotState.<GetConversationDataWithHttpMessagesAsync> - Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'

Tags: botframework, skype-bots, microsoft-skype-bot

I keep getting this exception after my bot is already active for hours. I'm not using any state API, and I've replaced the data store with one from Azure extensions

```
        Conversation.UpdateContainer(builder =>
        {
            var store = new TableBotDataStore(Configuration.GetConnectionString(MainStorageAccountName));

            builder.RegisterModule(new AzureModule(Assembly.GetAssembly(this.GetType())));

            builder.Register(c => store)
                   .Keyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(AzureModule.Key_DataStore)
                   .AsSelf()
                   .SingleInstance();
        });
```

It's ASP.NET Core app, and everything is working fine for hours, before this exception appears. I'm using the latest versions of Nuget packages

Exception:

```
Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'
       at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.BotState.<GetConversationDataWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.BotStateExtensions.<GetConversationDataAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ConnectorStore.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IBotDataStore<Microsoft-Bot-Connector-BotData>-LoadAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.CachingBotDataStore.<LoadFromInnerAndCache>d__11.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.CachingBotDataStore.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IBotDataStore<Microsoft-Bot-Connector-BotData>-LoadAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.BotDataBase`1.<LoadData>d__16.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.BotDataBase`1.<LoadAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTaskManagerBotDataLoader.<LoadAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ExceptionTranslationDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SerializeByConversation.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUser.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUser.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.LogPostToBot.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.Skype.ChatService.Bot.Rail.ActivityHandlers.MessageActivityHandler.<HandleAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 0):

the `Bot.Builder` package is not intended to work with AspNetCore, so basically you are trying to use the SDK in an unsupported way and this is most likely what is causing this error.  I am assuming that you are trying to use dialogs while using net core.  The SDK was not built with the intention of supporting net core.  Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3941) one of our users found a workaround for this which may help you overcome this issue.